# Not getting consistent answers using Lommel functions to calculate Fresnel difraction patterns

Tags: diffraction

I am trying to calculate the difraction pattern at a distance z=50mm behind a circular aperture from an on-axis point light source r0=0.6m in front of the aperture. I am doing this for a variety of aperture sizes ranging from 100 micron to 800 micron diameter.

I'm basing my calculation on the formallism in Klaus D. Mielenz's paper "Algorithms for Fresnel Diffraction at Rectangular and Circular Apertures", Journal of Research of the National Institute of Standards and Technology, 103,497 (1998). Although the same equations appear in other papers and in Born and Wolf.

The solution is given in terms of Lommel functions U and V, where approximately U converges in the classical shadow area and V converges in the classical illuminated area. The paper gives aproximate closed for solutions on the optic axis and at the shadow boundary.

When I calculate the diffraction pattern using the U functions I get agreement with the  losed form solution at the shadow boundry, and numerical values similar to those given for by the closed form solution at the optic axis.

However when I calculate the pattern in the illuminated area using the V functions I get numberrical values that are much, much larger and don't match the closed form solutions.

I've gone over my equations several time, comparing them to what is in the literature, and can't find an error.

Can anyone here help?

Here is a link to a PDF of an annotated MathCad file that implements the calculation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bilirjv6g012lje/Fresnel%20%20Pinhole%20Mielenz-Lommel%20rtf.pdf?dl=0